# Extract text from comlex captcha

Tags: python, captcha, decode, tesseract, noise

I need to decode this kind of Captcha.
http://www0.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=13934152

After a bit modification with ImageFilter, ImageEnhance looks like this.

http://www0.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=32704628

But this is still far from being recognized by Tesseract.

The problem is that the captcha is not static hence all the noise and stuff changes.

I am wondering if there is a more sophisticated approach to extract the white text out of it. Something more generic.

Comment: You could simply write a small preprocessing program that iterates over the pixels and if the pixel is (nearly) white make it black, if it isn't make it white. This should be straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to break the captcha you might be able to go around it. mitmproxy can filter and modify requests so you end up not receiving a page where you need to fill in a captcha.